# How to use two Matrix to draw a one plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, simulation

I am new to MatLab and trying to learn how can I use two matrix to draw a plot. I am working with "IEEE118Topology" data which represent 118 points/nodes in a power grid. One data set is 118x3. This represent the `location` of each node in a graph. Using the command:

`plot(Location(:,2),Location(:,3),'-ro'); %I can draw this plot with all 118 nodes.`

[image: Location data set]

But I have the second data-set that is 118x118. This data-set shows which nodes are connected to which nodes. Rather than plotting by just the location, Can you please tell me if there is a way I can combine both of these Matrix. Final plot should be as follows:
[image]

Both these datasets are attached in the following link:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/98na8s16ggl1dqz/AABgvwy9RPjIJv4fNbt2WFrKa?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Matlab's in-built function [`GPlot`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gplot.html)

The second matrix you are referring is the 'Adjacency matrix', while the first matrix is the 'coordinates'.

```
%// as your actual coordinates are in 2nd and 3rd column 
Coordinates = Location(:,[2 3]); 

gplot(Adjacencymatrix,Coordinates);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining with comments and example code. That works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: I have one last question related to this. If I want to highlight node 69 in this graph. How would I plot that?

Comment: @DP. Try this: `scatter(Coordinates(69,1),Coordinates(69,2),radius,[],'filled');`
change the radius size according to your need.

Comment: Thank you. by changing the radius size didn't work on my end. but typing in `scatter(Coordinates(69,1),Coordinates(69,2),'filled');` worked fine. Can you please tell me what is 1 and 2 stands for

Comment: @DP. 1 stands for 1st column i.e x- param. similarly 2 stands for 2nd column i.e y-param.